# How to disable instant linting from [Python (parser)] in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The Python parser in Visual Studio Code 1.25.1 lints any error directly while typing.

How can I turn that off?

I would like to disable the live-parser-linting.
I do not want to completely disable linting from pep8 or pylint too.

Maybe the issue got adressed here too:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2270

I found a setting for "List of surpressed diagnostic message" but I do not know, what to insert here (or if this is even the right place) nor do I find any documentation for the python.analysis.disabled settings on the web.

Help appreciated.

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
    "",
],
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Seems there is a list here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I am assuming you have the latest version of the Python extension for VS code installed as this won't have anything directly to do with VS Code 1.25.1]

If you are using the new language server from the Python extension then errors as you type do not turn off at the moment (you referenced the specific issue suggesting having a setting to turn that off).

If you're not using the new language server than the extension only runs linters on save, which would mean you have automatic saving as you type turned on and that's triggering the constant linting of your code. Tweak your settings to not automatically save and that will stop constant linting (and you can specify settings in VS Code for specific languages if you only want to change this for Python).

Comment: Ah, okay. That explains my issue clearly. Is there a possibility to downgrade my Python-Extension? I guess it is the new language-server, that is affecting my performance as well (notably poorer then before). Is there any documentation on how I could configure it to suit my needs? Can I switch it?

Comment: The new language server is off by default, so turn it on you would have set `"python.jediEnabled": false`. Simply set that back to `true` and you will switch back to the older IntelliSense enginen.